# Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open \TestAutomation\cypress.json&#x27;

Tags: node.js, json, npm, cypress, test-runner

Trying to launch the Test Runner  of Cypress first time through command - node_modules.bin\cypress open

But getting an unexpected error-
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open \TestAutomation\cypress.json'

Comment: This sounds like a permissions error within the project folder. Is it on a network? Does the same occur on the local drive?  Which OS?

Comment: saved on one drive

Comment: Try it locally.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention that much information, plus you misformatted some of it, so I can't really be precise in my answer.

However, I'd do:

- check that `cypress.json` is valid
- check that `package.json` is valid
- add a new script to `package.json`:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "open": "cypress open"
  }
}
```

and then run `$ npm run open`

- clear npm cache: `> npm cache clean --force`
- install latest version of npm as admin: `> npm install -g npm@latest`

Comment: Thanks for answering. May be I will just explain the steps which I am doing.-    1. npm init 2. creating package in my test automation folder. 3. installing cypress with -npm install cypress --save-dev 4. then trying to open Test runner with -  node_modules\.bin\cypress open

Comment: I tried the above steps, Still I am getting the issue. Please note I am getting this error displayed on Test runner UI. Test runner is getting opened, but with error. -Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open \TestAutomation\cypress.json'

Comment: Then share more information - your cypress.json, package.json, screen of the Cypress test runner, your test case where this happens.

Comment: I have answered. Please see

Comment: Your `package.json` file is not a valid json, you need to fix that.